# 3D drawing in lines, not displaying 3D in Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a 3D DWG drawing of only points and lines. I uploaded and translated it, with output format:

> 'type':'svf',
>                                                               'views':[
>                                                                   '2d',
>                                                                   '3d'
>                                                               ]

In front end,

> ```
> geometryItems = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(document.getRootItem(), {
>     'type' : 'geometry',
>     'role' : '2d'
> }, true);
> ```

Viewer shows 2D drawing, as if been flattened.

If I change 'role' from 2d to 3d, viewer doesn't show up, because geometryItems.length == 0.

Any way I can show 3D drawing with line/point in 3D, please? Thank you.

PS: I loaded the file to A360, same result. Then I downloaded it from A360, it was 3d as original.

Comment: Question edited with a PS.

Comment: I'm checking that for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (August, 2016), 2D geometries (e.g. lines, points) are not supported in Viewer 3D.